# Is there a way to compare two different class and return False if they are not the same

Tags: python-3.x

I am given different farm animals and their age and I want to know how to compare the classes that are different and returning `False` if they are.

I have tried returning `not __eq__` but it doesn't seem to work well.

```
from src.winged_animal import WingedAnimal
class Duck(WingedAnimal):

    def __init__(self, age):
        WingedAnimal.__init__(self, age)


    def make_sound(self):
        return WingedAnimal.make_sound(self) + " - quack, quack"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.age == other.age:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __ne__(self, other):
        if self.age is not other.age:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

So if given `Chicken(2) == Duck(2)`, I want to return `False` since the classes are different.

Comment: Side-note: Your test for `if self.age is not other.age:` is wrong; `is not` is an identity based test, you wanted `!=`, which is a value based test. Didn't fix in my answer, because the real fix is to omit `__ne__` entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly type check, because otherwise duck-typing (unfortunate name in this circumstance) means anything with an `age` that has the same value is equal:

```
class Duck(WingedAnimal):

    # No need to implement __init__ when it does nothing but delegate to superclass; that works automatically

    def make_sound(self):
        return super().make_sound() + " - quack, quack"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Duck):
            return NotImplemented  # Becomes False if other side also returns NotImplemented
        return self.age == other.age  # No need to test and explicitly return True/False

    # No need to implement __ne__; on Python 3, it's automatically implemented in terms of __eq__
```

Comment: It still says if I do Chicken(2.1) == Duck(2.1), they equal

Comment: @CollegeStruggles: Make sure `Chicken`'s `__eq__` implemented similarly (except only accepting `Chicken`). If it doesn't have `__eq__`, check the implementation of `WingedAnimal`.